# For best chess players.... Help me

Tags: strategy, chessboards

I have one question in my mind that while playing chess game with real person...
.
I also want to become winner.not only me but all starters.
.
1. What do you feel.
2. How do you think.
3. How can you beat your  opponent.
4.how do you make strategy.
.
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: At the moment, covering all 4 points in your question is nearly impossible. It is just too brad to fit in a single post. That is mostly the reason why others downvoted, and why your question might be closed. Please rephrase the question so it can address a "smaller" topic or delete it and ask all of those 4 points as separate questions. This is just my advice. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Even these questions separately are too broad to be answered. "3. How can you beat your opponent?" Unless you want an answer like "Play good moves" or "Checkmate" it is too broad

Comment: @Alan: Indeed, I have missed that... Well, I hope OP understood what we have meant to say... Good catch, you have a "sharp eye". Best regards.

Comment: the question may be broad. the answer doesn't have to be. there are lot of moderators down voting questions unnecessarily. don't understand why this is put on hold when there are already 2 answers.

Comment: apart from the third question, the rest are not so broad. you just have to say how you feel - calm, tense, etc. and what are your thought processes.

Comment: when the person posted his first question about unbeatable opening, my comment was considered as too harsh and was removed. And as you see, this person continues to pollute the site with useless questions.  Sometimes it make sense to tell the person blantly that his question is useless and does not make any sense.

Comment: @guru do you really want this site to have such kind of questions? There are many good questions are not answered here, so may be it is better to look into them, not answering another "I do not know how to move pieces, so how can I become a word champion fast (approximately in 2 months)"

Comment: Its not only my question... Its all starters question...

Comment: This is a very very vague question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth is on the board.  Focus your efforts on discovering the truth about the position and what the position needs.  Understand each position as best you can, then play the move that makes your position better.

Don't just look for the answer inside yourself, but solicit outside knowledge.  Ask others, including your opponent after a game; chess players love to brag about how much they understand about the position, even when they lose.  There are also some good books that are very helpful in learning how to break down a position.

Answer (score 0):

1. Feelings are not really relevant, are they?  Happy to be playing I guess.
2. What is my opponent planning?  Is there a real threat?  What are my options?  Do I have any opportunities?
3. Do not be intimidated by a strong opponent, you can still give them a good game. Likewise, never underestimate a weak opponent, even if they're chasing material at the expense of position with unguarded pieces everywhere, you could still lose.
4. Just play carefully.  Some aggressive moves your opponent makes turn out to be no threat whatsoever, so think before you react.  Similarly, sometimes defensive moves can turn the game on its head.